# Laravel socialite package Facebook login always redirect to Facebook homepage

Tags: laravel

I am using the Laravel socialite package to integrate Facebook login. But when a new user logs in using a Facebook account sometime its redirects to the correct page but sometimes it redirects to the Facebook home page. But it should be redirected to the application dashboard.

I couldn't figure out the exact issue.

My callback URL is like this

`https://example.com/auth/facebook/callback`

```
  public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }
```

```
 public function callback()
    {
       $facebook_user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback method, you can login and redirect like this (only for example):

```
public function callback()
{
    $facebook_user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();
    $user = User::updateOrCreate(['facebook_user_id' => $facebook_user->getId()], [
        'name' => $facebook_user->getName(),
        'email' => $facebook_user->getEmail(),
        'password' => Hash::make('test'),
        'status' => strval(Status::active)
    ]);
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    return redirect()->route('your-user-dashboard');
}
```

see also: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite#authentication-and-storage